# contributing to ASP .NET open source projects

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know how i can start contributing to ASP .NET projects. I love to learn it but I cannot currently get experience on the job.

Just out of curiosity, is contributing to open source ASP .NET projects regarded as good professional experience?

Thanks in advance!

Subbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend choosing one that you have an interest in, is well known and has some manageable chunks of work that need doing.  If you can work on something that can be demonstrated easily, then even better - you can say something like "I implemented the search feature on foo.net, which you can see at foo.net/search".

Answer (score 1):

Certainly that contributing to open source project can help you progress in your career.

Browse www.codeplex.com and find a few projects you can contribute to.

Limit your choice. It's better to work on one very well, than on 5 very badly.